# Pandas Transpose part of dataframe

Tags: dataframe, transpose

I try to transpose a part of dataframe but I don't if I can have the result needed.

My df is like (excel extract):

| code A | code B | June | July | August |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324325 | 3243. | 0,3. | 0,5. | 0,4. |
| 884543 | 7954. | 0,1. | 0,5. | 0,43. |

And I try to have:

| code A | code B | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324325 | 3243. | June | 0,3. |
| 324325 | 3243. | July | 0,5. |
| 324325 | 3243. | August | 0,4. |
| 884543 | 7954. | June | 0,1. |
| 884543 | 7954. | July | 0,5. |
| 884543 | 7954. | August | 0,43. |

Is it possible to have it by easy way in pandas of I have to do some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transpose is a dataframe melt here:

```py
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['code A', 'code B'], value_vars=['June', 'July', 'August'], var_name='Month')
```

Comment: Thx a lot, pandas is magic :)

Comment: Magic until you use it enough to get familiar =)